# Are there design patterns/best practices in writing dynamic SQL in stored procedures?

Tags: sql-server

I'm an experienced programmer but I'm new to SQL/databases so please bare with me :).

One of my current tasks involve editing (and refactoring, if needed) a dynamic generated SQL statement in a stored procedure. Are there any "best practices" or "design patterns" that I can follow for writing stored procedures in general or better yet, stored procedures that generate long (300 lines) dynamic sql statements?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How about starting with this article, ['The Curse and Blessings of Dynamic SQL'](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html) by Erland Sommarskog?

Comment: Just in time .. same answers

Answer (score 8):

Best is to read [The Curse and Blessings of Dynamic SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html) by  Erland Sommarskog.

Also read [Using Dynamic SQL in Stored Procedures](http://www.sqlteam.com/article/using-dynamic-sql-in-stored-procedures) and [Stored Procedures - Executing & Dynamic SQL](http://www.toadworld.com/platforms/sql-server/w/wiki/10260.stored-procedures-executing-dynamic-sql.aspx)

Comment: Travis beat you to answering the question. Thanks again for the answer. :)

Comment: @burnt1ce as long as we all help the community .. its fine for me. At the end we are all here to help each other and learn.